# how to apply Guava BloomFilter in steaming data

Tags: java, duplicates, streaming, guava, bloom-filter

I have a streaming of keys. and i want to check if the key has appeared in the latest , say 1000, keys. I want to use Guava BloomFilter which has a limit of number of insertions to avoid Over-Saturated.
so i can use it in the following way:

```
BloomFilter<Integer> filter = BloomFilter.create(
  Funnels.integerFunnel(),
  1000,
  0.01);
```

my question is 
1) if i use BloomFilter in the declared way above, i have to maintain a window of 1000 elements and create a new bloomfilter for each new window.
but i cannot check the duplications in window transition.
2) if i want to check duplicates in the stream which has unlimited number of keys. is BloomFilter still a good way to check duplications?